# Extracting data from .txt file yields chinese characters

Tags: php

I'm taking data from a submitted .txt file through `fopen` so I can compare it with a hardcoded string containing a row of headers for validation purposes.

The validation fails even when the conditions are met. I echoed both variables to see what was wrong and found out one of them (`$headers`) outputs chinese characters instead of the intended string.

Code:

```
$fn = fopen($_FILES["polizas"]["tmp_name"], "r");
$result = fgets($fn);
$headers = "seccion;propuesta;poliza;endoso;tipo endoso;desc tipo endoso;pol que renueva;iva;tipo doc;nro doc;apellido;domicilio;cod postal;telefono;localidad;provincia;fecha emision;fecha inicio;fecha vcto;canal pago;desc canal pago;origen;productor;organizador;moneda;item;marca;modelo;cero Km;motor;chasis;patente;tipo carroceria;desc tipo carroceria;cobertura;desc cobertura;cod acc1;desc acc1;valor acc1;cod acc2;desc acc2;valor acc2;cod acc3;desc acc3;valor acc3;cod acc4;desc acc4;valor acc4;suma aseg;prima;recarg;der emision;sellos;imp tasas;otrod;bonif;iva;adminis financ;premio;cant cuotas;ajuste;tipo vehiculo;desc tipo vehiculo;codigo uso;descripcion uso;año fab;nro prestamo;vcto cuota1;vcto prestamo;tipo prestamo;tipo operacion;seccion pol.paquete; poliza pol.paquete;";

echo $headers;
echo $result;
```

Here's the output of both variables, stored on pastebin since SO triggers a spam flag if I add it here:

https://pastebin.com/p3xxwvh2

Note that in this particular case, both variables SHOULD contain the same string.

Also, something I've noticed is that if I echo the variables in inverse order (`$headers` first and `$results` second) the result is different, `$headers` yielding the correct string and `$result` almost doing the same but with a few � characters in between.

I've checked if this is an encoding issue with the .php file itself but it doesn't seem to be the case (UTF-8).

Comment: And what is the character encoding of the text file you are reading there …? Seems to be something other than UTF-8 - so you will have convert the data _into_ UTF-8 first after reading it, before you can compare it to variable values that _are_ in UTF-8 (because they are part of the script, that you saved in that encoding), or before outputting it as part of an UTF-8 encoded response makes sense.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, you were right about the .txt file. I was receiving an UTF-16LE which was messing things up, using `mb_convert_encoding` I managed to get rid of all weird interactions. Would you mind proposing your comment as an answer so I can vote it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've checked if this is an encoding issue with the .php file itself but it doesn't seem to be the case (UTF-8).

The encoding of the text file you are reading the data from is also relevant.

Seems to be something other than UTF-8 here - so you will have convert the data into UTF-8 first after reading it, before you can compare it to variable values that are in UTF-8 (because these values come from the code, and that was saved in UTF-8), or before outputting it as part of an UTF-8 encoded response will give usable results.